# Отключить перевод строки при записи в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне записать файл этим скриптом без лишних пустых строк? То есть при записи в файл по непонятной мне причине к каждой строке добавляется "\n". а мне этого не надо бы. Код:

```
import requests

addr = requests.get('http://fh79272k.bget.ru/py_test/index.html')
#addr = requests.get('http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/weekend_projects/site_himmler_homepage/index.php')
print(addr.status_code)

print(addr.text)

try:
    f2 = open("text2.txt", 'w')
except Exception:
    print('open error')
except:
    print('error')
else:
    try:
        f2.write(addr.text)
    except Exception:
        print('write error')
    except:
        print('error')
    else:
        print('write OK')
finally:    
    f2.close()
```

Comment: судя по всему, они записаны в addr.text/addr.status_code, оф.маунал ничего не говорит про такие особенности, dip3 без запар пишет в одну строчку несколькими командами.

Answer (score 1):

Запустил ваш пример кода.
Получил ровно тот же самый текст, что и в исходном коде страницы http://fh79272k.bget.ru/py_test/index.html

Каюсь, пробовал в никсах, Python2.7
В порядке бреда: может, покопать в сторону os.linesep и проч. параметров системы?

Comment: Проверял на 3.4 (win7) -- тоже самое, лишних \n нет